# Troubles hosting a Dart app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud, dart

I'm trying to host a Google Dart site in the cloud. So far I've found one tutorial at:

http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/08/running-dart-in-cloud-with-heroku.html

but I've not been able to get this to work despite following it exactly. I'm also waiting on an invite from [dartvoid.com](http://dartvoid.com). Is there any other way of getting my site live with Dart now?

Comment: What problem are you having with the article?

Comment: The code is old on that post, sorry about that. Update coming!

Comment: Code has been updated in the post. Please post the exact errors you are getting and we'll help you out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Seth, I checked the heroku logs and was able to see that I had not changed the name of the main.dart file I was using. It worked once I changed it. Your example is very clear for the data. I'm not that familiar with heroku so now I'm going to play around with it to see how to show my pages(routes).

Comment: Yes you can get your site live by getting yourself a VPS server and just installing Dart on it and deploying your app there. :)

Comment: you can also deploy on OpenShift. You just have to create a "Do it yourself" application and configure the start hook to download/install a dart vm.

Comment: Hi @basheps glad you got it working. Can you answer your own question here? It's OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample in [Seth's article](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/08/running-dart-in-cloud-with-heroku.html) works fine. I had to change the file listed in Procfile to the dart file that the 'main' function is in.